# Blank Page when clicking on 'View All Site Content' or 'Site Settings'

Tags: 2010

I'm having a problem with 1 site collection where all my subsites render blank screens for any pages in the Layouts folder.

For example, I have a site on port 80, http://testsite.ca and when I click on the link for view all site content (http://testsite.ca/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx) or site settings (http://testsite.ca/_layouts/settings.aspx) the page displays as expected.

But for all subsites under this, I get blank white screens.  For example, under this site I created a subsite using the blog template, and the site works fine and I can add blog items, manage posts, etc.  But if I try to navigate to any items under that subsite that reference the layouts folder (for example http://testsite.ca/blog/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx or http://testsite.ca/blog/_layouts/settings.aspx) then the page is blank.

It shouldn't a permission problem since I'm a site collection administrator, and any new web apps or site collections created don't have this problem, so it appears limited to just this site.

Hopefully this is something someone here has seen before?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: is ur site https ? try https://Sitename.com

Answer (score 1):

Open your site with sharpoint desigener, then go to all files -> _catalogs -> master page right click on v4.master or Seattle.master depending the version you are using and set it as default and custom master page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load different page from settings, e.g. _layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx
Do you get error? 
I had the same issue and I was missing masterpage. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem like this today , I found that page "viewlsts.aspx" in  hive is corrupted (contains strange symbols) don't know know , I just replaced it with a working one and it worked fine